# React/React Hooks: Need to trigger validation for input when a user unchecks a checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-hooks

I have a component with an input field and checkbox. As it stands the checkbox disables the input field and clears any validation errors. What I'm trying to do is create additional functionality that if someone unchecks that box and the input becomes active again, a validation will run and once again prompt the user to enter an email. I have a code sandbox [here](http://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-breeze-2ly5h) for example and my full component listed below

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {
  Col, Row, Icon, Input, Tooltip
} from 'antd'
import Checkbox from '../elements/Checkbox'
import Markup from '../core/Markup'

function validateEmail(value) {
  const errors = {}
  if (value === '') {
    errors.email = 'Email address is required'
  } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)) {
    errors.email = 'Email address is invalid'
  }
  return errors
}

const CustomerDetails = ({ customer }) => {
  const { contact = {}, account = {}, site = {} } = customer || {}
  const [disableInput, setDisableInput] = React.useState(false)
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState({})
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState(contact.email)

  function onBlur(e) {
    setErrors(validateEmail(e.target.value))
  }

  function clearInput() {
    setInputValue(' ')
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

  function CheckboxClick() {
    if (!disableInput) {
      clearInput()
    }
    setDisableInput(prevValue => !prevValue)
    setError({})
  }


  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col span={10}>
          <h4>
            PRIMARY CONTACT EMAIL &nbsp;
          </h4>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledInput
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            disabled={disableInput}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            isError={!!errors.email}
          />
          {errors.email && <ErrorDiv>{errors.email}</ErrorDiv>}
        </Col>
        <Col span={2} />
        <Col span={8}>
          <StyledCheckbox
            value={disableInput}
            onChange={CheckboxClick}
          /> EMAIL
          OPT OUT{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}



const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: left;
`
const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  &&& {
    background: white;

    input + span {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      border: 2px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.black};
    }

    input + span:after {
      width: 12.5px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    input:focus + span {
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
    }
  }
`

const ErrorInput = ({ isError, ...remainingProps }) => (
  <Input {...remainingProps} />
)

ErrorInput.propTypes = {
  isError: PropTypes.bool
}

const StyledInput = styled(Input)`
  max-width: 100%;
  background: white;

  &&& {
    border: 2px solid ${props => (props.isError ? '#d11314' : 'black')};
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 35px;
  }
`

const ErrorDiv = styled.div`
  color: #d11314;
`


export default CustomerDetails
```

Comment: It's hard to follow what you trying to do, try and put a MINIMAL WORKING example and explain in few words desired input and output, I suggest adding a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. Why validate input only on `onBlur`
2. Why the checkbox has a side effect for clearing output? Add a button for it.
3. Too much boil trap code.

Here is a minimal example, you should figure it out from here what suits you:

```js
const CustomerDetails = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);
  const [showMsg, setShowMsg] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Insert "hello"
      <Row>
        <Input
          value={email}
          onChange={e => {
            setEmail(e.target.value);
            setIsValid(isValidEmail(e.target.value));
          }}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
      </Row>
      <Row>{!isValid && showMsg && 'Email is invalid'}</Row>
      <Row type="flex" justify="space-between">
        <Col>
          <Checkbox
            value={!disabled}
            onChange={() => {
              setDisabled(prev => !prev);
              setShowMsg(prev => !prev);
              setIsValid(isValidEmail(''));
              setEmail('');
            }}
          />{' '}
          EMAIL OPT OUT
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};
```

A Demo which validates the word `hello`:

[image: Edit flamboyant-newton-mhjq7]

Comment: Both the validation and the clearing effect of the checkbox are requested functionality from the client so I'm working within those confines

Comment: Ok, I updated the clearance on a check, hope it helps

Comment: So I think I still need to add more detail to my question. If a user unchecks that checkbox another validation should run to check if the field is empty and because it will be empty after being cleared initially, the error message will flash saying email is required

Comment: And you don't understand how to accomplish that? Did you try it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to no. I tried manipulating my ```CheckboxClick``` method to run the validation after ```setDisableInput``` but nothing is working

Comment: Well, I updated the answer... You just left to add CSS for "flashing msg".

Comment: Hmm this still doesn't work because if I type 'hello' and then click the checkbox to clear and then click the checkbox again to make the input active I don't get an error message even though the input is blank. I'm going to keep trying to alter the Checkbox click method

Comment: now it works... just add `setIsValid(isValidEmail(''));` in `Checkbox` onChange

Comment: This works, but is still outside the scope of my component because it doesn't actually check the validity of an email address. I'm not trying to be a pain, I just can't implement this with my component. Thank you for the help though

Comment: So what is the problem? Just replace to `const isValidEmail = value => !/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value)` ?

Comment: I'm trying to splice your implementation with mine as part of the onBlur functionality. The validation for email format isn't firing the error message correctly so I'm working through that now

Comment: This doesn't work for my component but hopefully it will help someone else, thanks again for the help